# Ajax repeating twice

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am working on some jQuery to check if a cell in a table has been edited.  If it has, the revision gets sent back to the database via ajax.  I am using a timeout delay to give the user 2500 milliseconds between keystrokes to make their full correction and catch when they are finished.  I am also using blur bypass the timeout delay if they click out to a different `td` in the html table.  Once ajax is complete I add a "saved" class to the `td` and have ajax inside an `if` statement so that ajax only happens if the "saved" class is not present. This only allows ajax to happen once.

**My issue:**  Even with the added precautions above, when the `td` is not blurred and left to timeout instead ajax happens twice.  I can verify this because the message box comes up twice and values in my table are doubled (as they are supposed to because the table data is purposely added to any old data in that spot)

**My Question:** Why might this be happening and how can I fix this?

**Side Note:**  The toastr code has also stopped working and I am not sure why.

```
$('td').on('input blur', function(e) {

    var timeoutDelay=2500;

    if( e.type == "blur"){
        timeoutDelay=1;
    }

    // If NOT already saved...
    if( !$(this).hasClass("saved") ){
        var _this = $(this); // preserve reference to the input field here

        clearTimeout(saveTimeout);
        saveTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
            console.log(_this)
            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "updatedatabase.php",
                data: { 
                    content: _this.text(), 
                    date: _this.siblings().first().text(),
                    prod: $('tr:first-child th:nth-child(' + (_this.index() + 1) + ')').text(),
                    old: old
                }
            })
            .done(function( msg ) {
                alert( msg );
                // Add the "saved" class to prevent other saving
                _this.addClass("saved");
            });

            toastr.options = {
                "positionClass": "toast-top-center",
                "onclick": null,
                "timeOut": "2500",
            }

            toastr.info(old,'Database Updated!<br><br>Your Previous Amount Was:');

            _this.prop('contenteditable', false);

        }, timeoutDelay);
    }
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    var old;
            
    $('td').click(function(){
                
        old=$(this).text();
                
        $(this).prop('contenteditable', true);
                
                
    });
            
    var saveTimeout;
            
    // Remove the "saved" class on keydown
    $('td').on('keydown', function(e) {
        $(this).removeClass("saved");
    });
    
    $('td').on('input blur', function(e) {
                                
        var timeoutDelay=2500;
               
        if( e.type == "blur"){
            timeoutDelay=1;
        }
                
        // If NOT already saved...
        if( !$(this).hasClass("saved") ){
            var _this = $(this); // preserve reference to the input field here
            
            // Add the "saved" class to prevent other saving
            _this.addClass("saved");
            
            clearTimeout(saveTimeout);
            saveTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
                console.log(_this)
                $.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: "updatedatabase.php",
                    data: { 
                        content: _this.text(), 
                        date: _this.siblings().first().text(),
                        prod: $('tr:first-child th:nth-child(' + (_this.index() + 1) + ')').text(),
                        old: old
                    }
                })
                .done(function( msg ) {
                    alert( msg );
                });

                toastr.options = {
                    "positionClass": "toast-top-center",
                    "onclick": null,
                    "timeOut": "2500",
                }

                toastr.info(old,'Database Updated!<br><br>Your Previous Amount Was:');
                        
                _this.prop('contenteditable', false);
                        
            }, timeoutDelay);
        }
    });
            
            
    $("td").hover(function(){
                                
                
                    
        $(this).addClass('highlight').siblings().first().addClass('highlight');

        $('tr:eq(1) th:eq('+$(this).index()+')').addClass('highlight');
                
                
    },function(){
                
                
                    
        $(this).removeClass("highlight").siblings().first().removeClass('highlight');

        $('tr:eq(1) th:eq('+$(this).index()+')').removeClass('highlight');
                
                
    });
    
});
```

```css
table,th, td {
  
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
        
}

.highlight {
    
    background-color:#E0E0E0;
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/1.3.1/css/toastr.css" rel="stylesheet"/> 
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/1.3.1/js/toastr.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Item #</th>
    <th>1234567</th>
    <th>7654321</th>
    <th>5678945</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Product</th>
    <th><u>22 ounce Dark</u></th>
    <th><u>12count 4oz Dark</u></th>
    <th><u>24count 6oz TJ</u></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>2016-01-03</th>
    <td>13587</td>
    <td>2203</td>
    <td>4111</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>2016-01-04</th>
    <td>14111</td>
    <td>3247</td>
    <td>4332</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>2016-01-05</th>
    <td>13212</td>
    <td>3101</td>
    <td>3911</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>2016-01-06</th>
    <td>16335</td>
    <td>3299</td>
    <td>4001</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>2016-01-07</th>
    <td>15421</td>
    <td>3100</td>
    <td>4078</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You've not included the important bit of your code - namely how you handle events.

Comment: I guess using `_this.prop('contenteditable', false);` makes element losing focus and so fire `blur` event before you set class `saved` from ajax `done()` callback

Comment: Not to mention that it would be possible to focus and blur again while the ajax is running.

Comment: As a first quick guess: currently if an `updatedatabase.php` takes more than `timeoutDelay` to work and return its response, then its pretty normal that `$.ajax()` fires again. So you might do `_this.addClass("saved") _before_ `$.ajax()` rather than in its `.done()` part.

Comment: @cFreed that was a great thought.  To check this I did as you mentioned and pulled the `addClass` out of `.done()` and inserted it right inside of the if statement so it was the first thing to be done.  This did not solve the problem though.

Comment: @Jamiec you would like me to add a small example of the table in a snippet?  I will add that now

Comment: @Brandon can't hurt!

Comment: In the case of `blur`, `timeoutDelay = 1` seems _very_ short, whatever happens elsewhere. So it might be interesting to test different values, starting with big ones like 100. Then, if successful, decrease it till the issue appears again.

Comment: @cFreed that was my way of removing the delay, because blur should only happen if the html table `td` is clicked out of, meaning they were done editing that `td`

Comment: @Jamiec I added a snippet to the bottom of the post.  The odd thing is that toastr is working in that snippet, yet it no longer works on my live site.  The whole js file was copied right into the snippet, so there isnt any other javascript that could be causing an issue with toastr.